# Gradle how to make configuration variables

Tags: gradle, configuration

Gradle: define a configuration foo as following:

```
task fooJar(type: Jar) {
    ...
}

configurations {
    foo.extendsFrom("compile")
}

artifacts {
    foo fooJar
}
```

How to write if configuration name is a variable? For example,

```
['foo', 'bar'].each {

    task "${it}Jar"(type: Jar) {
       ....
    }

    configurations {
        "$it".extendsFrom("compile")
    }

    artifacts {
        "$it" tasks["${it}Jar"]
    }

}
```

### UPDATE after answer:

The 2nd part: adding artifact:

```
artifacts.add(config, tasks["${it}Jar"])
```

Error:

```
> Could not find method add() for arguments [configuration 'foo', task 
'fooJar'] on object of type 
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultArtifactHandler.
```

Comment: How is `helloJar` defined? Could you provide full example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@see [ConfigurationContainer](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer.html) which is returned by [Project.getConfigurations()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getConfigurations())

eg

```
Configuration config = configurations.create(it)
config.extendsFrom configurations.getByName('xxx')
```

Comment: Thanks. the 2nd part gives me error. updated question.

Comment: You're going to have to start thinking for youself one of these days... see [ArtifactHandler](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/ArtifactHandler.html)